# Does SQL Server 2019 honor OPTION (USE HINT ( 'FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION' ))

Tags: performance, sql-server-2019

We had several pieces of code that when the 2014 Cardinality Optimizer came out performed very poorly. By adding this oip

Comment: this question seems to finish quite abruptly.

Answer (score 3):

On my 2019 instance, clicking the *Display Estimated Execution Plan* toolbar button and expanding the execution plan XML for a given query, you should see

`CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70"` (old) when using the `FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION` hint

and

`CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="150"` (new) when NOT using the `FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION` hint

(assuming no overriding trace flags)